# Calculate integral $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{(z-2)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate integral $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{(z-2)^2}dz$

I think it is equal to $0$ from Cauchy theorem... since the circle $|z|=1$ is contained in some region where $f(z)$ is holomorphic, is it?

Comment: I think you mean the right thing, but the relevant bit is not "the circle $\lvert z\rvert = 1$", it is the disk $\lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1$.

Comment: Oh thats true, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct. The function $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-2)^2}$ has singularity at $2$ and it's outside the disc $|z|\leq1$.